# is there is a problem with using a variable-length array in c for embedded systems?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, embedded

someone told me that initializing an array with non-constant value is wrong, but I need to know why.

```
int length = 5 ; 
int array[length];
```

Comment: This is called a VLA and it's not wrong per se. But a very old compiler (like you might sometimes find in the embedded environment) might not support it. Also it's somewhat notorious for not being supported in C++ while some popular compilers will tolerate it nevertheless.

Comment: That's not initializing the array, that's the length of the array. It's a [Variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It's not necessarily wrong to do, only the Sith deal in absolutes. However, older compilers, and some new ones, won't handle it.

Comment: The problem with VLAs is that if the length is taken from untrusted (or simply not well-validated) input it will easily blow up your stack.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Otoh, this is true for all kinds of dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Ctx With heap allocation the error is detectable, with stack overflow it will simply crash.

Comment: @Blaze: Variable length array support is optional in the current C standard, and compilers for embedded systems may be a bit rinky-dink and not support it even if they are not old.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How exactly the program malfunctions is secondary; the point is: you have always to look twice when doing memory allocation based on untrusted input, regardless if its the stack or the heap

Comment: @Ctx Of course, the input should be always validated. But my point is that you have the C means to do so with `malloc` (check the return value and such), but you don't have such a means to check the stack allocation (VLA, `alloca`) and need some linker magic involved.

Comment: Please note that the code you show is only valid _inside a function_. The code is invalid for a global array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it got demoted to an optional feature? That's interesting to know, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to Linus Torvalds, Variable-Length Arrays bring nothing of positive value to the world of embedded programming and bring problematic baggage with them including stability and speed issues.  It is recommended to just use a sufficiently large fixed-size array when reasonable, or allocate the array on the heap when not.

> VLA's are problematic for embedded and systems programming
>   because the stack is usually very limited. Code generation
>   is also generally negatively affected, which can make it
>   a very inconvenient feature (frame pointers aren't free,
>   and registers can often be used more effectively for other
>   things).
>
> If your array length is limited to a known value, you're
>   often better off just using the maximum size. And if the
>   maximum size is too large for that to be a good approach,
>   see above about limited stack sizes.
>
> In short: VLA's don't buy you anything in embedded and
>   systems programming, and they do cause problems.

[...]

> Some people really don't seem to realize that embedded and
>   system programming is **different** from "normal"
>   programming. Resources are limited and you **must not**
>   just fail. You generally cannot just say "oops, I don't
>   have enough memory, I'll just exit".

https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=121531&curpostid=121621

Further opinion from Linus, taken from the Linux Kernel Mailing List:

> AND USING VLA'S IS ACTIVELY STUPID! It generates much more code, and
>   much _slower_ code (and more fragile code), than just using a fixed
>   key size would have done.

https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/7/621

I also think it is worth reiterating Eric PostPischil's comment that as of C11, VLAs are optional.  You'll see a greater variety of hardware architectures when working in embedded systems, some of which can be more difficult to implement VLAs on, so there's not a trivial chance that you may come across a system that does not support them.

From what I've read on that matter, it seems to be that VLA's are typically implemented making use of a Frame Pointer, but not all architectures have a Frame Pointer.

Comment: He has a point. If you know that the maximum size of the array isn't going to cause problems then why not allocate a fixed array of the max size that may be required. If you don't know that the maximum possible size required is safe then you shouldn't be using a VLA.

Comment: Despite the fact that I agree with his _opinion_ in this case, when did Linus Torvalds author of the monster behemoth that is Linux become an arbiter of what is right and wrong for embedded systems?

Comment: @Clifford I felt he was worth quoting not just for having an opinion on the matter, but because he explains *why* they're bad rather succinctly.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Fair enough.  My point was rhetorical rather than actually wanting to know.  The quotes date from 2012 and 2018, and reflect what every embedded developer knew in 1999 when VLAs were introduced, so his points were hardly a revelation.  This too is if course _an opinion_ ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Using arrays with non-constant length may be a problem on embedded system because of limited resources. You must be sure that the available memory is sufficient in all cases. This is difficult to prove if you use dynamic allocation or variable length arrays.

It may be OK if there is an upper bound (i.e. an upper limit for the value of `length` in your example) and if you can prove that your memory (stack size, total RAM, ..., whatever is applicable) will still be sufficient in the worst case.

That's why coding rules for embedded or critical systems often pose restrictions on what you are allowed to do.

Comment: If there isn't an upper bound then you shouldn't be using a VLA. If there is a (safe) upper bound then why not just allocate an array of that size?